# What will be the best practices in my code to prevent sql injection?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection

What will be the best practices to prevent sql injection? My client asked me to prevent sql injection. I used this structure for data inserting or updating

```
public bool Add(GreenItem aGreenItem, Employee emp)
        {
            aGreenItem.GreenItemCode = new CommonBLL().GetMaxId("[GreenItemCode]", "[Processing].[GreenItem]", "GTM");
            using (SqlConnection objConnection = Connection.GetConnection())
            {
                SqlTransaction transaction = objConnection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
                try
                {
                    string query = aGreenItem.GreenItemId == 0 ? "GreenItem_Create" : "GreenItem_Update";
                    SqlCommand sqCmd = new SqlCommand(query, objConnection, transaction);
                    sqCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    if (aGreenItem.GreenItemId > 0)
                    {
                        sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GreenItemId", aGreenItem.GreenItemId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GreenItemCode", aGreenItem.GreenItemCode);
                    }

                    sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GreenItemName", aGreenItem.GreenItemName);
                    sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeasurementUnitId", aGreenItem.MeasurementUnitId);                    
                    sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", aGreenItem.Description);
                    sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", aGreenItem.IsActive);
                    sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GLTId", emp.GLTId);
                    sqCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatorId", emp.EmployeeId);
                    sqCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

I used this function to get the Max ID Which is called from the function above

```
public string GetMaxId(string coloumName, string tableName, string prefix)
        {
            string maxId = ""; string selectQuery = "SELECT '" + prefix + "'+RIGHT('0000000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(MAX(RIGHT(" + coloumName + ",10)), 0)+1,10),10) maxID FROM " + tableName + " ";
            using (SqlConnection objConnection = Connection.GetConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand sqCmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, objConnection); sqCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (IDataReader dataReader = sqCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        maxId = dataReader["maxID"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                objConnection.Close();
            }

            return maxId;
        }
```

What needs to be added to for best output?

Comment: You are already preventing SQL Injection, by using SqlParameters instead of manipulating the string directly. Good Job. We can't see what CommonBLL().GetMaxId() does though, maybe post that too

Comment: Using parametrised queries and **Safely** quoting dynamic objects (if you have them) is the best way. On a separate note, [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) & [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Added the GetMaxId function on POST. @Milney

Comment: OK - there is definitely scope for SQL injection in GetMaxId, since you're assembling the SQL statement with strings passed through as parameters without any escaping, It would be better to use parameters as you have in Add(). However if you're only ever going to call GetMaxId() with hard-coded strings in the app, and never with strings the user can influence, you might get away with this.

Comment: I always called this function on another function and passed fixed parameters @Rup

Comment: That statement, however, is wide open to injection, @touhidalam69 . You have a dynamic table name that you are not sanitising, and are injecting values instead of parametrising them..

Comment: Do we already have a canonical question that explains why `catch { /* throw away all exception information */ ... return false; }` is a terrible crime (committed against the poor soul who will have to provide customer support for that application)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server, avoiding SQL injection comes down to one simple thing

- use parameters, rather than concatenation, for all inputs

You're already doing that in the code that we can see, so: great job so far.

People often mistakenly say "use stored procedures" to avoid SQL injection, but "stored procedures" and "SQL injection" are actually entirely orthogonal - you can avoid SQL injection without stored procedures, and you can *cause* SQL injection *inside* stored procedures. We *can't see* what `GreenItem_Create` / `GreenItem_Update` do internally - they're *probably* fine if they are simple `INSERT` / `UPDATE` operations. As long as they don't do `EXEC (@somethingYouConcatenated)` internally, you should be fine. If you *do* ever need to build T-SQL inside T-SQL, make sure to use `sp_ExecuteSQL` to correctly parameterize that dynamic SQL.